# Show only payload in GCP Logs Viewer (Stackdriver)

Tags: google-cloud-stackdriver

Is there a way to show only log payload (plain text) and get rid of all the metadata noise in GCP Logs Viewer (previously Stackdriver Logs Viewer)?  GCP Logs Viewer breaks a plain text log file into many json records with lots of noise and makes it also impossible to read. Basically, I want the same experience as I view a log file on a VM.

Answer (score 1):

You can export the logs using the cli tool here:
https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/logging/read#--view
For specifically having only the textPayload, use "--format=value(textPayload)" and pipe the output to a file. Example:

```
gcloud logging read "resource.type=k8s_container AND resource.labels.project_id=my-project-id AND labels.k8s-pod/app=my-pod AND severity>=DEFAULT" --format=value(textPayload) > mylogfile
```